# 'Use <database> ' statement not executing T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

Okay, this seems funny for a simple script: but I really need this small piece to execute well.

```
DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(50)
SET @dbName = 'rx_lab'
DECLARE @SQL02 NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL02 = 'USE ['+ convert(nvarchar(50),@dbName) +']'
exec sp_executesql @SQL02

SELECT DB_NAME()
```

This still returns the 'master' database (instead of 'Rx_lab')
I have even tried using

```
exec ('use '+@dbName)
```

No change. It didn't work even without the conversion to nvarchar.
However, when I use 'USE [Rx_lab]' directly it returns well. This is part of stored procedure where the @dbName is main parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sp_executesql` creates a new execution context which ceases to exist when the executed statements return.  The USE only has effect within the `sp_executesql`.  Try this

```
SET @SQL02 = 'USE ['+ convert(nvarchar(50),@dbName) +']; SELECT DB_NAME();'
```

and you'll get what you're after.

Comment: @Michael_Green thanks buddy. However I would still need to exec the assignment from your answer. Yep, this will give me the DB_NAME() in the executed context but statements AFTER this will Not be using the new db assignment - which is what I want...

Comment: on second thought, if I qualified each statement with a 'USE' statement then indeed it will execute in that db context. Thanks. Example:  
  SET --SQL02 = 'USE ['+ convert(nvarchar(50),@dbName) +'] IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N''rxpipewami'') DROP USER [rxpipewami] '

Comment: You have it right. The USE statement only has effect within the SQL submitted to `sp_executesql`. As soon as `sp_executesql` returns the USE is no longer in effect.

Answer (score 0):

> but statements AFTER this will Not be using the new db assignment - which is what I want

You can use 3 part naming `dbname.schema.objectName`. Below is an example to get you started. You can modify as per your needs :

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(max)
    ,@SQLText VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @dbname = min(NAME)
FROM master..sysdatabases
WHERE STATUS NOT IN (
        128
        ,1024
        ,6292500
        )
    AND STATUS & 1024 <> 1024
    AND STATUS & 128 <> 128
    AND STATUS & 512 <> 512
    AND STATUS & 32 <> 32
    AND dbid > 4


WHILE @dbname IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    --PRINT @dbname

    SELECT @SQLText = '
    select ' + ''''+quotename(@dbname)+'''as DBNAME,'  + 'count(1) as NoOFTables from ' + quotename(@dbname) + '..sysobjects where [type] =''U'' '

    PRINT @SQLText

    EXEC (@SQLText)

    SELECT @dbname = min(NAME)
    FROM master..sysdatabases
    WHERE STATUS NOT IN (
            128
            ,1024
            ,6292500
            )
        AND STATUS & 1024 <> 1024
        AND STATUS & 128 <> 128
        AND STATUS & 512 <> 512
        AND STATUS & 32 <> 32
        AND dbid > 4
        AND NAME > @dbname
END
```